# Remove all occurrences of \ from string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, escaping

I am trying to get an array of objects from the server, using JSON.

The server sends me the following string.

```
"[{\"DealComment\":null,\"DealVotes\":[],\"DealId\":1,\"CompanyId\":1,\"StartDate\":\"2012-12-13T00:00:00\",\"EndDate\":\"2012-12-16T00:00:00\",\"CouponCode\":\"Test Coupon 1\",\"Description\":\"Test Deal Description 1\",\"VoteUp\":null,\"VoteDown\":null,\"ViewCount\":null,\"Title\":\"Test Deal 1\"},{\"DealComment\":null,\"DealVotes\":[],\"DealId\":2,\"CompanyId\":1,\"StartDate\":\"2012-12-16T00:00:00\",\"EndDate\":\"2012-12-17T00:00:00\",\"CouponCode\":\"Test Coupon 2\",\"Description\":\"Test Description 2\",\"VoteUp\":null,\"VoteDown\":null,\"ViewCount\":null,\"Title\":\"Test Deal 2\"},{\"DealComment\":null,\"DealVotes\":[],\"DealId\":3,\"CompanyId\":1,\"StartDate\":\"2012-12-14T00:00:00\",\"EndDate\":\"2012-12-15T00:00:00\",\"CouponCode\":\"Test Code 3\",\"Description\":\"Test Description 3\",\"VoteUp\":null,\"VoteDown\":null,\"ViewCount\":null,\"Title\":\"Test Deal 3\"},{\"DealComment\":null,\"DealVotes\":[],\"DealId\":4,\"CompanyId\":1,\"StartDate\":\"2012-12-12T00:00:00\",\"EndDate\":\"2012-12-13T00:00:00\",\"CouponCode\":\"Test Coupon 4\",\"Description\":\"Test Description 4\",\"VoteUp\":null,\"VoteDown\":null,\"ViewCount\":null,\"Title\":\"Test Deal 4\"},{\"DealComment\":null,\"DealVotes\":[],\"DealId\":5,\"CompanyId\":2,\"StartDate\":\"2012-12-12T00:00:00\",\"EndDate\":\"2012-12-14T00:00:00\",\"CouponCode\":\"AwD\",\"Description\":\"Very awesome deal!\",\"VoteUp\":null,\"VoteDown\":null,\"ViewCount\":null,\"Title\":\"Awesome Deal 1\"}]"
```

Now, if you look at the string closely, you would notice that it contains an **`\"`** instead of every **`"`**. The string cannot be formatted to a JSONArray right now. So, I need to replace every occurrence of **`\"`** with **`"`** , which would have a pretty easy task, had **`\`** not been an **escape sequence**.

I tried using the following code.

```
String jsonFormattedString = jsonStr.replaceAll("\\", "");
```

But it gives me the following exception.

```
12-19 00:35:59.575: W/System.err(444): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_BAD_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE near index 1:
12-19 00:35:59.575: W/System.err(444): \
12-19 00:35:59.575: W/System.err(444):  ^
```

My whole code, in case it is of any use :

```
public void getAllDealsFromServerJson()
{

    String apiUrl = "http://passme.azurewebsites.net/api/TestApi/";


    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
    HttpResponse response;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try{
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(apiUrl);
        json.put("requestType", "getalldeals" );

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());  
        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        response = client.execute(httpPost);
        Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
        jsonResponse = response.toString();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String jsonStr = reader.readLine();
        Log.d("String Response", jsonStr);
        String jsonFormattedString = jsonStr.replaceAll("\\", ""); // gives error
        Log.d("Formatted String", jsonFormattedString);
        //JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(jsonFormattedString);
        /*JSONObject finalResult = new JSONObject(tokener);
        Log.d("JSON Response", "" + finalResult.optString("Title"));*/
        JSONArray resultArray = new JSONArray(jsonFormattedString);
        Log.d("JSON Array Result Length", "" + resultArray.length());
        Log.d("JSON Array Result ", "" + resultArray.getJSONObject(0).optInt("DealId"));

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this:

```
String jsonFormattedString = jsonStr.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Because the backslash is the escaping character in a regular expression (`replaceAll()` receives one as parameter), it has to be escaped, too.

Comment: `String jsonFormattedString = jsonStr.replace('\\', '');` is easier since you don't have double escape.  Docs say:        Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

Comment: @mikejones If you notice from the question, that's what the OP was originally doing and it wasn't working.

Comment: @swayam glad to hear that! please don't forget to accept this solution, if it was helpful for you :)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Not quite. The OP was using `replaceAll(String, String)`, whereas @mikejones was suggesting using `replace(char, char)`.  (Unfortunately, @mikejones's solution wouldn't have worked either, since there is no "empty char" `''`.)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez : It was more than helpful! It was awesome! And well, SO wants me to wait for another 6 minutes before I can hit the accept mark. So, I guess I am 6 minutes away from accepting it! :D

Comment: This may solve the problem at hand, but it could cause problems down the road.  Here we're assuming that the only use of backslashes is to prefix a double quote, and that may be true for _this_ example data.  The root cause though is that the server is doubly JSON encoding the data.  Without addressing that specifically, your code has a hidden bug that will only blow up when eventually the result has a genuine backslash which gets stripped accidentally.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez , Could you please help me. Here is my JSON object 

{"checkpoint":"false","fname":"ekq1LbxBvCo=","livingArrangement":"","education":"","gender":"Male","mobileNumber":"9IG8RjfnTxlcvNXaMS8Rhg==","mailId":"CslHja5q40ssG12Cf55L\/w==","significantOther":"","age":"","maritalStatus":"Single","agreed":"false"}

Acc. to your method, I am first converting into JSON string and then trying to replace "\". But this is not working for me.
Could you suggest any other way remove "\" from mailId inside JSON object?

Answer (score 16):

Actually the correct way would be:

```
String jsonFormattedString = jsonStr.replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

You want to replace only `\"` with `"`, not all `\` with *nothing* (it would eat up your slashes in json strings, if you have ones).
Contrary to popular believe `replace(...)` also replaces all occurrences of given string, just like `replaceAll(...)`, it just doesn't use regexp so it usually be faster.

Comment: Oh. wasnt aware of that. but isnt it the same as replacing \" with " ?

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Swayam Yes, if we assume that given json won't contain `\` anywhere

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Reading this now reminded me of the problem more than four years old. :)

Comment: What if we want to keep a `\"` in the string? it will remove that too.

Answer (score 11):

Just use:

```
try {
        jsonFormattedString = new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue().toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

See documentation

Comment: This would be the correct way to do, instead of using regex or string replace the \\.

Comment: This should be the right answer, by replacement method there may come some other formatting issue in JSON.

Comment: Thanks. hello everybody use this method.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: in which package/lib is JSONTokener is from ?

Comment: This is a class from the org.json package, which is a part of the JSON-java library

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your incoming string is doubly JSON encoded.  You should decode it, then decode that again.

Here's my best guess as to how you might do that in Java:

```
JSONArray resultArray = new JSONArray(new JSONString(jsonFormattedString));
```

I'm assuming here that `JSONString` is a type.  Your actual solution may vary.

Under normal circumstances, I'd expect a service to give you JSON straight up.  It appears that this services is giving you a string (encoded according to the JSON spec) which *contains* JSON.

It's the difference between the following:

```
String someJSON = "[0, 1, 2]";
String doublyEncodedJSON = "\"[0, 1, 2]\"";
```

Notice the extra leading and trailing quotes? That's because the latter is a string of JSON.  You'd have to decode it twice to get the actual object.

Comment: And how exactly do I do that sir ?

Comment: Added my best guess---I don't do Java development often, but I work with JSON daily.  Good luck!

Comment: Well, actually sir.. I just replaced the \" with " and tested the resultant string here http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ . It showed up properly, the way I expected it to.

Comment: Yep, I agree that it works for the particular example data that you're currently getting back from the third-party JSON service.  I explain in a comment on the other answer why this masks a hidden bug which will appear when the data eventually contains a real backslash.

Comment: Yes sir. I do understand that. I will have a look at how to double decode JSON in java.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use:

```
str.replace("\\","");
```

replace takes string as param,  replaceAll uses RegEx. it may work like this also:

```
str.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got it working using the first answer. Thanks a lot anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
jsonObj.toString()
        .replace("\"[", "[").replace("]\"", "]")
        .replace("\\\"{", "{").replace("}\\\"", "}")
        .replace("\\\\\\\"", "\"")
```