# how to remove backslah and double quote from string in java to make json

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

```
class Request {     
     private String requestid;
     private String contenttype;
     private String service;
     private String requestjson;
}
```

making this object to json using Object mapper but the mapper is returning me

```
"requestjson\":\"{\\\"username\\\":\\\"farhan\\\",\\\"password\\\":\\\"farhaan\\\"}\"}"}
```

How can I remove this extra

```
\\\
```

I tried

```
 jsonOutput.replaceAll("\"",Character.toString ((char) 34));
```

Comment: What is the code that you are using to make JSON out of that object!

Comment: [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is for regular expressions. You mean [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Comment: i was trying with replaceAll("\\",""); it will remove my backslash but its not removing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939925/remove-all-occurrences-of-from-string

Comment: I'm not sure you should remove it. It looks like it's been encoded multiple times, so you should decode it multiple times.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this.

```
String jsonString = jsonStr.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

The reason you have to double up the (already doubled) backslashes  is that [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) takes a regular expression and a single backslash is [used in regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: If you're not using the features of regular expressions, you shouldn't be using `replaceAll`. That is what [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) is for