# JSONObject with Json as one parameter

Tags: json

I am trying to create a JSONObject which has two parameters, for example:

```
JSONObject jobj;    
jobj.put("data", {"hey":"hi"} ;
```

But the problem is as soon i create a JSONObject, it gets converted like this:

```
"data":"{\"hey\":\"hi\"}
```

My expectation is, I want it to look like this:

```
"data":{"hey":"hi"}
```

Also the second parameter is JSON as it random.

Comment: Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939925/remove-all-occurrences-of-from-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939925/remove-all-occurrences-of-from-string)

Comment: Hi Sriram , that is based on converting input String.But my input String is fine.Only after creating JSONObject it gets converted in that form.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all backslashes of json coverted string with empty value