# Formatting JSONObject into JSONArray

Tags: java, json, string, hashmap, formatting

I have a JSONObject and I need to place inside a JSONArray.

This is my code:

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> Data = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,String> element1 = new HashMap<>();
String JSONString = "{\"optGroups\":{\"Information\":{\"optStatus\":false,\"updateDate\":\"01/03/2017 01:16:03\"},\"freeToUse\":{\"optStatus\":false,\"updateDate\":\"01/03/2017 01:16:03\"}},\"optInsights\":{\"RemindPaymentTransfer\":{\"optStatus\":false,\"updateDate\":\"01/03/2017 01:16:03\"},\"BalanceIsTooLow\":{\"optStatus\":false,\"updateDate\":\"01/03/2017 01:16:03\"}}}";
element1.put("key1",JSONString);
Data.add(element1);
return new JSONArray(Data);
```

When I print the JSONArray I see the original String with "\" symbols.

How to fix the formatting so I will keep the JSONArray but see a valid JSONObject with "key":"value"?

Comment: Please check this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939925/remove-all-occurrences-of-from-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this maybe:

```
s.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject jsonObject= json.getJSONObject("{\"optGroups\":{\"Information\":{\"optStatus\":false,\"updateDate\":\"01/03/2017 01:16:03\"},\"freeToUse\":{\"optStatus\":false,\"updateDate\":\"01/03/2017 01:16:03\"}},\"optInsights\":{\"RemindPaymentTransfer\":{\"optStatus\":false,\"updateDate\":\"01/03/2017 01:16:03\"},\"BalanceIsTooLow\":{\"optStatus\":false,\"updateDate\":\"01/03/2017 01:16:03\"}}}");

Iterator x = jsonObject.keys();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

while (x.hasNext()){
    String key = (String) x.next();
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject.get(key));
}
```